# IModelBinder: access the raw data of the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I am trying to look at the text sent in a POST through the `IModelBinder` interface.  I have something like:

```
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("my special content type"))
        {
            var data = ???
```

...where the ??? should be the text that was sent in the POST.  It should be one lump of text (I think) but I don't see how to access it.  Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: You can use the `ModelBindingContext`, for example if you want the value from a form control named `LastName` then `var lastName = GetValue(bindingContext, "LastName"),`

Comment: I don't want "LastName" though... I want the whole enchilada.  How can I see the whole of the text sent back?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the method in this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241710/accessing-the-raw-http-request-in-mvc4 to read the raw http request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, per @ScottRickman's advice, I looked at the article at [Accessing the raw http request in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241710/accessing-the-raw-http-request-in-mvc4) and saw how to apply this to the IModelBinder:

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("my special content type"))
    {
        var body = GetBody(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request);
        var model = MyCustomConverter.Deserialize(body, bindingContext.ModelType);
        return model;
    }
}

private static string GetBody(HttpRequestBase request)
{
    var inputStream = request.InputStream;
    inputStream.Position = 0;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
    {
        var body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return body;
    }
}
```

This worked exactly as desired.